# How to obtain the cost of each employee in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

How would I be able to obtain the totalcost and loop through each employee to get the cost individually?

Expected output:

```
?- make_team([batman, superman, aquaman], Heroes, TotalCost).
Heroes = [[batman, bruce, wayne, 342000], [superman, clark, kent, 475000], [aquaman, arthur, curry, 5000]],
TotalCost = 822000.
```

```
% Returns a list of available heroes.
% Each hero's information is also stored as a list.
employees(E) :- E = [
  [superman, clark, kent, 475000],
  [batman, bruce, wayne, 342000],
  [wonder_woman, diana, prince, 297000],
  [green_arrow, oliver, queen, 210000],
  [flash, barry, allen, 184000],
  [aquaman, arthur, curry, 5000] ].

% Helper rule that may be used to extract information from an
% employee.  For instance, if you know an employee's name,
% you can use this rule to look up their salary.
hero(HeroName, SecretIdentFname, SecretIdentLname, Salary) :-
  employees(EmpList),
  member(H, EmpList),
  H = [HeroName, SecretIdentFname, SecretIdentLname, Salary].


% Given a list of hero names, return the list of heroes
% and the total cost of all heroes.  (Since there should
% only be one match, you might consider using a green cut).
make_team([], [], 0).
make_team([HeroName|Tail], HeroList, TotalCost) :-
  employees(EmpList),
 % CODE HERE
```

Comment: You should reconsider your data representation. The better way in Prolog would be to assert several facts: `hero(superman, clark, kent, 475000).` and `hero(batman, bruce, wayne, 342000).` etc. Then you only need a predicate to give you a list from a hero name, like `hero_details(Hero, [Hero, First, Last, Salary]) :- hero(Hero, First, Last, Salary).` then you can use `maplist(hero_details, HeroNameList, HeroDetailsList).` You can similarly get a list of just the salaries, then do a `sumlist`.

Comment: I was given this how would I be able to recursively call the make team?

Answer (score 1):

```
employees(E) :- E = [
  [superman, clark, kent, 475000],
  [batman, bruce, wayne, 342000],
  [wonder_woman, diana, prince, 297000],
  [green_arrow, oliver, queen, 210000],
  [flash, barry, allen, 184000],
  [aquaman, arthur, curry, 5000] ].


make_team([], [], 0).
make_team([HeroName|Tail], HeroList, TotalCost) :-
    employees(EmpList),
    make_team(Tail, Z1, Z2),
    member( [HeroN, A, B, C], EmpList),
    HeroN == HeroName,
    append([[HeroN,A,B,C]],Z1,HeroList),!,
    TotalCost is Z2 + C.
```

Try that.